# Better button functionality with fragments - Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am fairly new to Android programming so I need a bit of help with the following problem. I need to know if there is a better way of adding button functionality when working with fragments. I am working on an application that has three activities. However, the second activity (see code below) is most important and largest activity where all the heavy lifting of the application is done. In this (second) activity ("DmpAct.java") I have a fragment container ("R.id.dmpFragContainer") where up 15 different fragments are swopped out and displayed to the user - one at a time - depending on what the user wants to do. So, when the "DmpAct.java" class starts a welcome fragment is loaded into the "dmpFragContainer" container and the user then clicks a button to go to the next fragment - which replaces the welcome fragment with whichever fragment is called up by the button that was clicked.

Dilemma: Currently the "DmpAct.java" is not doing much other than inflating the layout (UI) and successfully swopping out the various fragments when the buttons are clicked. I am implementing an OnClickListener on the root of the "DmpAct" activity as I make use of exactly 10 buttons in this activity. I am also using a custom fragment animation (flip animation) for all fragment swopping. I also need to ID which fragment is currently loaded and visible to the user (for subsequent interactions) so I supply a unique TAG for every fragment that gets swopped out to the FragmentManager ... everytime a button is clicked and a next fragment is loaded into the "dmpFragContainer".

... below is the code for the second activity - DmpAct.java ...

```
package com.wesoft.forgetfulme;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class DmpAct extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Fragment fragment;
Fragment newFragment;
String activeFrag;
FragmentManager FragMan;
FragmentTransaction TransAct;
Button birtListBtn, evenListBtn, appoListBtn, todoListBtn, specListBtn, dmpAddBtn, dmpExitBtn;


@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "CommitTransaction" })
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    // Hide the Title Bar of the Application --> Must come before setting the Layout...
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    // Hide the Status Bar of Android OS --> Can also be done later...
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);


    // Now you can draw the second Layout --> DMP Screen of the Application...
    setContentView(R.layout.dmp_act);

    // Instantiate the FragmentManager and FragmentTranstion...
    FragmentManager FragMan = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction TransAct = FragMan.beginTransaction();


    // Define or set the initial/start fragment to be loaded when the view is rendered...
    DMPWelcFrag startFragment = new DMPWelcFrag();
    TransAct.add(R.id.dmpFragContainer, startFragment);
    TransAct.commit();


    // Instantiate (or get references to) all buttons laid out in this Activity and set the onClickListeners...
    Button birtListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_bir_btn);
    birtListBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button evenListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_eve_btn);
    evenListBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button appoListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_app_btn);
    appoListBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button todoListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_tod_btn);
    todoListBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button specListBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_spe_btn);
    specListBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button dmpAddBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_add_btn);
    dmpAddBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    Button dmpExitBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dmp_exi_btn);
    dmpExitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();        

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.dmp, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void onClick(View v) {

    // Set the DMP CATEGORY and ACTION Buttons Actions here ...
    if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_bir_btn) {
        newFragment = new BirtListFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "BLF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("BLF");
        TransAct.commit();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "This Fragment's tag is  ...  " + newFragment.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_eve_btn) {
        newFragment = new EvenListFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "ELF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("ELF");
        TransAct.commit();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_app_btn) {
        newFragment = new AppoListFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "ALF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("ALF");
        TransAct.commit();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_tod_btn) {
        newFragment = new TodoListFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "TLF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("TLF");
        TransAct.commit();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_spe_btn) {
        newFragment = new SpecListFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "SLF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("SLF");
        TransAct.commit();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_add_btn && newFragment.getTag() == "BLF") {
        newFragment = new BirtEditFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "BEF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("BEF");
        TransAct.commit();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "This Fragment's tag is  ...  " + newFragment.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_add_btn && newFragment.getTag() == "ELF") {
        newFragment = new EvenEditFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "EEF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("EEF");
        TransAct.commit();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "This Fragment's tag is  ...  " + newFragment.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_add_btn && newFragment.getTag() == "ALF") {
        newFragment = new AppoEditFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "AEF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("AEF");
        TransAct.commit();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "This Fragment's tag is  ...  " + newFragment.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_add_btn && newFragment.getTag() == "TLF") {
        newFragment = new TodoEditFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "TEF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("TEF");
        TransAct.commit();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "The tag of this fragment is  ...  " + newFragment.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_add_btn && newFragment.getTag() == "SLF") {
        newFragment = new SpecEditFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "SEF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("SEF");
        TransAct.commit();
        // Toast.makeText(this, "The tag of this fragment is  ...  " + newFragment.getTag() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else {
        newFragment = new DMPWelcFrag();
    };


    // Set the DMP EXIT Button Action here ...
    if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_exi_btn) {
        Intent go2Main = new Intent(DmpAct.this, MainAct.class);                  
        startActivity(go2Main);
    }
    else;
};

}
```

PROBLEM: The problem is, currently as the code is (listed above), it does not even execute half the work that the "DmpAct.java" activity is suppose to do...and just look how heavy and repetitive the code is already. There are still text and other input validation (not evident from code list here – still pending) that need to be done with every button click and then the inputed values need to be saved in a bundle (and saved to a local database file on the mobile device) before the inputed data are passed to the next fragment for display to the user. Now, as is evident from this piece of code ...

```
else if (v.getId() == R.id.dmp_add_btn && newFragment.getTag() == "BLF") {
        newFragment = new BirtEditFrag();

        FragmentTransaction TransAct = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        TransAct.setCustomAnimations(R.animator.card_flip_right_in, R.animator.card_flip_right_out, R.animator.card_flip_left_in, R.animator.card_flip_left_out);
        TransAct.replace(R.id.dmpFragContainer, newFragment, "BEF");
        TransAct.addToBackStack("BEF");
        TransAct.commit();
```

... when the ADD button is clicked it checks to see which fragment is currently loaded in the "dmpFragContainer" (using the TAG supplied on the last fragment swop) and loads the next correct fragment. Now as simple as this process is suppose to be, the code seems too bulky to me as I am doing this exact same process for all 10 buttons used in this activity! So I need help with this. Is there a better way of implementing the same action without writing so much code and repeating the same code 15 or more times?

Please guys, I know this will give me performance problems when the "DmpAct.java" class file gets expanded to add more functionality. So any advice and help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Cheers,
SilSur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is going to cause performance issues but I am pretty sure you can reorganise your code a bit. Start using `Interfaces` instead of having if switches. So create an interface with methods which are common for all of your fragments and add the implementation to your fragment classes. Then you can use the interface to call the methods of the fragment you wish to appear. You can also create a method `fragmentType` which is going to return the type of the fragment which is active. Just play a bit with the interfaces around.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response...uhm...but I will first have to read up on the implementation of these "Interfaces" and "FragmentType" before I can say whether it will suit my needs for this application. I am still learning... Thanks nevertheless, AlecNash.

Comment: for the interface: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html and for the fragmentType will be a method that you will create

Comment: Thanks, AlecNash. I finally got it. Thanks for guiding me in the right direction...  :)